# Trying to get Protractor's location strategies in Node script (protractor.By)

Tags: webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs

I'm trying to setup protractor in a node script and I would like to get access to the location strategies. However, because I'm doing something stupid I am not seeing them on the protractor object:

```
var protractor = require('protractor');

//... Wrapping selenium driver

var by = protractor.By;

//console.log(by) returns '{}'
//and protractor.getInstance(); is returning undefined:
```

How might I get access to the selection strategies (by element, model etc). (I'm writing the script in this manner to work with CucumberJS, so, given the current setup I have I cannot simply run the protractor executable directly).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who cares to integrate Protractor and CucumberJS, the heuristic should be to execute protractor and have protractor execute cucumber, **not** the other way around.

My approach was completely wrong: Both protractor and CucumberJS are capable of integrating and executing the other's executable, however, using cucumberJS first would appear to be wrong. Rather I suggest using protractor to *Drive* the tests. Documentation for protractor integration with CucumberJS is extremely poor and difficult to find. Moreover there are a number of misleading pieces of information.

#### Right approach

See these [example files in the protractor repo](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/spec/cucumber) which, while not documented to my knowledge (or even acknowledged) provide what would appear to be an adequate means to integrate both tools. To execute it is necessary to have a [protractor config setup appropriately](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/cucumberConf.js)

#### Wrong approach

Problems: Protractor Location strategies don't appear to work. protractor.getInstace() is undefined. protractor.By == {}

Following examples such as [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/protractor-cucumber), the implied setup in cucumberJS and similar examples with selenium results in protractor not fully initialising. The effect is that the location strategies appear undefined. There may well be a means to make it work, but after digging through the source-code for days I cannot find it easily.